# QTreeView only edits in first column?

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, propertyeditor

I am trying to make a simple property editor, where the property list is a nested dict and the data is displayed and edited in a QTreeView.  (Before I get to my question -- if anyone already has a working implementation of this in Python 3 I'd love to be pointed at it).

Anyway, after much work I have my QAbstractItemModel and I can open a QTreeView with this model and it shows the data.  If I click on a label in the first column (the key) then it opens up an editor, either a text editor or a spinbox etc depending on the datatype.  When I finish editing it calls my "model.setData" where I reject it because I don't want to allow editable keys.  I can disable the editing of this by using flags and that works fine.  I just wanted to check that everything works the way that I'd expect it to.

Here is what doesn't happen:  if I click on a cell in the second column (the value that I actually want to edit) then it bypasses the loading of an editor and simply calls model.setData with the current value.  I am baffled.  I've tried changing the tree selectionBehavior and selectionMode but no dice.  I'm returning Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable in flags.  It seems to display fine.  It just won't open up an editor.

Any thoughts about what stupid mistake I must be making?  I'll include the code below, with some print statements that I'm using to try to debug the thing.

Thanks

PS  One thing that hung me up for a long time was that my QModelIndex members would just disappear, so the indices that I got back were garbage.  I found that by keeping a reference to them (throwing them in a list) that they worked.  This seems to be a problem that springs up a lot in Qt work (I had the same problem with menus disappearing -- I guess that means that I should think about it sooner).  Is there a "best practices" way of dealing with this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt4.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAbstractItemView

class PropertyList(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.myModel = PropertyListModel(self)

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if issubclass(type(index), list):
            item = self
            for key in index:
                item = item[key]
            return item
        else:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, index)


class PropertyListModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self, propList, *args, **kwargs):
        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.propertyList = propList
        self.myIndexes = []   # Needed to stop garbage collection

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        """Returns QModelIndex to row, column in parent (QModelIndex)"""
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QModelIndex()        
        if parent.isValid():
            indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
            parentDict = self.propertyList[indexPtr]
        else:
            parentDict = self.propertyList
            indexPtr = []
        rowKey = list(parentDict.keys())[row]
        childPtr = indexPtr+[rowKey]
        newIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, childPtr)
        self.myIndexes.append(childPtr)
        return newIndex

    def get_row(self, key):
        """Returns the row of the given key (list of keys) in its parent"""
        if key:
            parent = key[:-1]
            return list(self.propertyList[parent].keys()).index(key[-1])
        else:
            return 0

    def parent(self, index):
        """
        Returns the parent (QModelIndex) of the given item (QModelIndex)
        Top level returns QModelIndex()
        """
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()
        childKeylist = index.internalPointer()
        if childKeylist:
            parentKeylist = childKeylist[:-1]
            self.myIndexes.append(parentKeylist)
            return self.createIndex(self.get_row(parentKeylist), 0,
                                    parentKeylist)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        """Returns number of rows in parent (QModelIndex)"""
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0    # only keys have children, not values
        if parent.isValid():
            indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
            try:
                parentValue = self.propertyList[indexPtr]
            except:
                return 0
            if issubclass(type(parentValue), dict):
                return len(self.propertyList[indexPtr])
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return len(self.propertyList)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2  # Key & value

    def data(self, index, role):
        """Returns data for given role for given index (QModelIndex)"""
       # print('Looking for data in role {}'.format(role))
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            indexPtr = index.internalPointer()
            if index.column() == 1:    # Column 1, send the value
                return self.propertyList[indexPtr]
            else:                   # Column 0, send the key
                if indexPtr:
                    return indexPtr[-1]
                else:
                    return ""
        else:  # Not display or Edit
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        """Sets the value of index in a given role"""
        print('In SetData')
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        print('Trying to set {} to {}'.format(index,value))
        print('That is column {}'.format(index.column()))
        if not index.column():  # Only change column 1
            return False
        try:
            ptr = index.internalPointer()
            self.propertyList[ptr[:-1]][ptr[-1]] = value
            self.emit(self.dataChanged(index, index))
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def flags(self, index):
        """Indicates what can be done with the data"""
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags
        if index.column():  # only enable editing of values, not keys
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable #Qt.NoItemFlags

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PropertyList({'k1':'v1','k2':{'k3':'v3','k4':4}})

    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()

# I've played with all the settings on these to no avail
    treeView.setHeaderHidden(False)
    treeView.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
    treeView.setUniformRowHeights(True)
    treeView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked | 
                             QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked |
                             QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed |
                             QAbstractItemView.AnyKeyPressed)
    treeView.setTabKeyNavigation(True)                             
    treeView.setModel(p.myModel)
    treeView.show()

    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Comment: A clarification question: I don't see any code to let an editor appear for any column, so I would be surprised to see it work for the first column. Where do you let an editor pop up?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your "best practice" question here within the stack overflow format since i shouldn't provide answers in comments but the answer would not be an answer to your question. But, in short, qmenus should have a parent whereas you are not building the model indexes correctly. I'll try to answer your index question here but the qmenu question might be better as a separate question.

Comment: I've found your Qmenu question and added a second answer there. Hopefully that answer together with this one addresses your concerns about how to protect Qt objects from garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

@strubbly was real close but forgot to unpack the tuple in his `index` method.

Here's the working code for Qt5. There are probably a couple of imports and stuff that would need to be fixed. Only cost me a couple weeks of my life :)

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TupleKeyedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(sorted(kwargs.items()))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    item = item[k]
            return item
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            item = self
            previous_item = None
            for k in key:
                if item != ():
                    previous_item = item
                    item = item[k]
            previous_item[key[-1]] = value
        else:
            return super().__setitem__(key, value)

class SettingsModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root = data
        self.my_index = {}   # Needed to stop garbage collection

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            index_pointer = parent.internalPointer()
            parent_dict = self.root[index_pointer]
        else:
            parent_dict = self.root
            index_pointer = ()
        row_key = list(parent_dict.keys())[row]
        child_pointer = (*index_pointer, row_key)
        try:
            child_pointer = self.my_index[child_pointer]
        except KeyError:
            self.my_index[child_pointer] = child_pointer
        index = self.createIndex(row, column, child_pointer)
        return index

    def get_row(self, key):
        if key:
            parent = key[:-1]
            if not parent:
                return 0
            return list(self.root[parent].keys()).index(key[-1])
        else:
            return 0

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        child_key_list = index.internalPointer()
        if child_key_list:
            parent_key_list = child_key_list[:-1]
            try:
                parent_key_list = self.my_index[parent_key_list]
            except KeyError:
                self.my_index[parent_key_list] = parent_key_list
            return self.createIndex(self.get_row(parent_key_list), 0,
                                    parent_key_list)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0    # only keys have children, not values
        if parent.isValid():
            indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
            parentValue = self.root[indexPtr]
            if isinstance(parentValue, OrderedDict):
                return len(self.root[indexPtr])
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return len(self.root)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2  # Key & value

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            indexPtr = index.internalPointer()
            if index.column() == 1:    # Column 1, send the value
                return self.root[indexPtr]
            else:                   # Column 0, send the key
                if indexPtr:
                    return indexPtr[-1]
                else:
                    return None
        else:  # Not display or Edit
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        pointer = self.my_index[index.internalPointer()]
        self.root[pointer] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = TupleKeyedOrderedDict(**{'1': OrderedDict({'sub': 'b'}), '2': OrderedDict({'subsub': '3'})})

    model = SettingsModel(data)
    tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tree_view.setModel(model)
    tree_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep a list of indexes to prevent them being garbage collected.  This is needed because, as the documentation explains, the Python object referenced by the `internalPointer` of a `QModelIndex` is not protected from garbage collection by that reference.  However, your list is added to every time your Model is asked for an index so a new internalPointer is created even for the same Item in the Model.  Whereas Qt expects the index and therefore the internalPointer to be the same.  This is also problematic since it means the indexes list just keeps growing (as you can see if you add a debug print printing out the contents of `self.myIndexes`).

This is not trivial to fix in your case.  In most models, the internalPointer just stores a pointer to the parent item which is therefore never duplicated.  But that won't work in your case because items in the PropertyList don't know their parent. The easiest solution might be to change that, but the PropertyList shouldn't really be affected by its use in the Qt model.

Instead, I have built a dict which is used to find an "original" key list for any key list you build.  This looks a bit odd but it works and fixes your code with the fewest changes.  I have mentioned some alternative approaches at the bottom.

So these are my changes (really just the lines changing `self.myIndexes` but also changing the key list to be a tuple rather than a list so it can be hashed):

```
def __init__(self, propList, *args, **kwargs):
    QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.propertyList = propList
    self.myIndexes = {}   # Needed to stop garbage collection

def index(self, row, column, parent):
    """Returns QModelIndex to row, column in parent (QModelIndex)"""
    if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
        return QModelIndex()        
    if parent.isValid():
        indexPtr = parent.internalPointer()
        parentDict = self.propertyList[indexPtr]
    else:
        parentDict = self.propertyList
        indexPtr = ()
    rowKey = list(parentDict.keys())[row]
    childPtr = indexPtr+(rowKey,)
    try:
        childPtr = self.myIndexes[childPtr]
    except KeyError:
        self.myIndexes[childPtr] = childPtr
    newIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, childPtr)
    return newIndex

def parent(self, index):
    """
    Returns the parent (QModelIndex) of the given item (QModelIndex)
    Top level returns QModelIndex()
    """
    if not index.isValid():
        return QModelIndex()
    childKeylist = index.internalPointer()
    if childKeylist:
        parentKeylist = childKeylist[:-1]
        try:
            parentKeylist = self.myIndexes[parentKeylist]
        except KeyError:
            self.myIndexes[parentKeylist] = parentKeylist
        return self.createIndex(self.get_row(parentKeylist), 0,
                                parentKeylist)
    else:
        return QModelIndex()
```

This seems to work, though I've not done too much testing.

Alternatively you could use the internalPointer to store the parent model item (dictionary) and keep a mapping from model item to key list.  Or a mapping from model item to parent item.  Both of these need a little fiddling (not least because dictionaries are not immediately hashable) but both are possible.